# Disable logging when using external library

Tags: java, logging

I'm using a library ([jwbf](https://github.com/eldur/jwbf)) that use logging. It prints many informations that I don't need. How can I disable this? Why they enable logging by default? Logging is just for debug isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution [here](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.fr/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html) :

I added this dependency to my pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And I created a log4j.properties in src/main/resources and I put this :

```
    log4j.rootLogger=OFF, STDOUT
```